# Ajax not working beyone PhoneGap 3.7

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have this code :

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url: url.com,
            dataType : "json",
            data : { "rand" : Math.random(), "postcode" : localStorage['postcode']},
            error : function(error)
            {



            }
        }).done(function(objResult) 
        {
```

});

which worked perfectly in PhoneGap 3.7.0, but when I compile it with anything newer, the ajax returns a 404 not found error.

I have  `<access origin="*" />` and when I re-compile in 3.7.0 is goes back to working fine..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daily I am amazed at the variation of new ways to put the wrong subject in the subject line. Welcome the club of Amazing.

@ojsglobal,
you need to start reading the blog for [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/) and [Phonegap Build](http://phonegap.com/blog/).

The `whitelist` system has been in place since 3.x; in 4.x it is required; in 5.x you cannot access the internet without the `whitelist` system. You need to implement the `whitelist` system.

[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

We have also move to NPM plugin registry. You *may* need to move to your plugins to have *npm=source*

Read this unfinished blog for [Core Plugins Setup](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/plugins-core-setup.md)

You may also want to read the bold point in: 
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Best of Luck